# can you differentiate $y(x)=x^4 - 2x^2+8x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can you help me differentiate $$y=x^4 -2x^2+8x$$ with respect to $y$? Thank you.

Comment: Use $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ and the linearity of the derivative

Comment: Do you mean finding $\frac {dy}{dx} = y'$ or do you mean finding $\frac {dx}{dy} = x'$?

Comment: yes, Since you need the derivative of y with respect to x.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

Comment: What you're asking about is called implicit differentiation. You've been given an implicit relation between the independent variable $y$ and the dependent variable $x(y)$, and you have to solve for $x'(y)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Try using the chain rule on the terms on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{4x^{3}-4x+8}$. You must solve on $x$ the quartic polynomial equation $x^{4} -2x^{2} + 8x -y=0$ and replace $x$ in $\frac{dx}{dy}$ expression.

There exists a closed form for quartic polynomial equations that you can easily find in literature.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for implicit differentiation,

$$ 0 = x^4 - 2x^2 + 8x - y $$
$$ 0 = 4x^3x' -4xx' + 8x' - 1 $$

By the way, the reason it is called implicit differentiation is because you cannot explicitly represent $x$ as a function of $y$. If you attempt to separate the variables, it will not happen cleanly.

As a simple example, say we had the function $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and we tried to write $y$ as a function of $x$, we would have $y = \pm \sqrt{4 - x^2} $. You can see how this might be a problem.

Now what would happen if we differentiated with respect to $x$ in this case? Well, we know $y$ is a function of $x$, so we can write $x^2 + f(g(x)) = 4 $ and say $ f(y) = y^2 $ and $ g(x) = y $. Then if we apply chain rule, which is $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))g'(x) $, the following immediately follows

$$ 2x + f'(g(x))g'(x) = 2x + 2yy' = 0 $$

I hope that clears things up for you.